# Can every subset $\Lambda \subset M$ of a fixed closed manifold $M$ be realized as a hyperbolic set of a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $f: M \to M$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Recall that a set $\Lambda \subset M$ is called hyperbolic with respect to some $C^1$ diffeomorphic function $f:M \to M$ if it is $f$ invariant and if there exists a $Df$-invariant splitting $T_{\Lambda}M=E^{u}\oplus E^s$ such that $Df_x$ contracts on $E^s(x)$ and expands on $E^u(x)$.

Now fix an arbitrary set $\Lambda \subset M$.

I was wondering whether one can always construct or at least assert the existence of a function $f: M \to M$ with hyperbolic set equal $\Lambda$.

Comment: If we want $Df$-invariant splitting for which both stable and unstable spaces are present, then the (partial) answer is "no". Consider 2d manifolds. An existence of $Df$-invariant splitting leads to an existence of an $f$-invariant foliations without singularities on $\Lambda$ (due to [Hirsch-Pugh-Shub](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183532203)? might be mistaken). The only surfaces that support such foliations without singularities are [tori and Klein bottles](https://books.google.ru/books?id=C2HoCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR5&hl=ru&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q&f=false). ...

Comment: ... So you can't take an arbitrary surface inside $M$ as $\Lambda$ and provide a hyperbolic dynamic for it. The reasons why I'm posting this as a comments: 1) I remember these things on folklore level, especially the part about invariant foliations without singularities; 2) I can't say anything about the case when splitting of $T_{\Lambda} M$ on surface has only unstable or stable subspace — I feel like that it's impossible to have such case, but can't prove it right now.

Comment: First a correction: $E^u$ is the unstable direction and so $Df_x$ expands on $E^u$, and $E^s$ is the stable direction and so $Df_x$ constracts on $E^s$. In other words, $|Df_x(v)| > |v|$ for every $v \in E^u$ and $|Df_x(v)|<|v|$ for every $v \in E^s$.

Comment: Second a question: Are you requiring the expansion/contraction to be uniform in any sense, for example if $v \in E^u$ then $|Df_x(v)| \ge C |v|$ for some constant $C>1$ independent of $v$? If so, then a necessary condition is that $\Lambda$ be closed.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for the correction. And yes, we have uniform constants $C >1$ and $\tau \in (0,1)$ such that $\vert Df^k_x(v) \vert \leq C \tau^k \vert v \vert$ for any $v \in E^s(x)$ for instance. But why is $\Lambda$ necessarily closed? We proved in class that the closure of a hyperbolic set is again hyperbolic, which would be unnecessary if $\Lambda$ was closed anyway.

Comment: Well then, what does your last phrase mean "with hyperbolic set equal $\Lambda$" mean? Because I took it to mean "such that $\Lambda$ is THE hyperbolic set, meaning the union of all $f$-orbits for which the splitting condition holds" but now it seems that perhaps you meant only that $\Lambda$ is the union of some of the $f$-orbits for which the splitting condition holds?

Comment: @LeeMosher I do apologize for my sloppy phrasing: I do indeed just mean SOME set, such that the splitting condition holds. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. From my point of view the simplest example is $S^1$.

First note that the requirement on invariant splittings is automatically satisfied, although you still need an argument. What I am saying that if $S^1$ is a hyperbolic set, then either all stable spaces have dimension $1$ or all unstable spaces have dimension $1$.

Recall that the dimensions of the stable and unstable spaces are locally constant (this is the simplest nontrivial property of a hyperbolic set). Being integers, covering $S^1$ by intervals where the dimensions are constant and taking a finite subcover you get the former claim.

Let's assume that all stable spaces have dimension $1$ (you can treat in a similar manner the case when all unstable spaces have dimension $1$). Then paths on $S^1$ are contracted after sufficiently many iterations (if $c$ and $\lambda$ are the usual constants in the notion of a hyperbolic set, then after $n$ iteration provided that $c\lambda^n<1$). Now take a closed path that covers $S^1$ with the same initial and final points. It has length $1$ but after $n$ iterations it has length smaller than $1$ (this follows from estimating the length using the derivative). On the other hand, the image of the path is itself.

This contradiction show that $S^1$ cannot be a hyperbolic set.